# what is the reason for sqlite roll back?

Tags: sql, multithreading, sqlite

I am having the serialized access to sqlite database. All of the threads are using the same database handle.

sqlite3_config(SQLITE_CONFIG_SERIALIZED);

During one of transaction statement involving many insert statements, I am deleting rows in another thread. Both are trying to modify the same table.

I am getting the transaction is roll backed. I wanted to know whether this can be the reason for the roll back.

Can you please help me to find the issue?. Thanks in advance.

Regards,
Rajeev

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One connection has one transaction.
Therefore, when using multiple threads, you should use one connection for each thread.

SQLite's threading modes can prevent the database structures themselves from becoming corrupted, but when multiple threads try to do anything with the database at the same time, they will still interfere with each other's data.

Comment: You mean to say that if we are trying to modify the table from the other thread, it can make the database in to a inconsistent state?

Comment: It will be in a consistent state as far as the database itself is concerned (i.e., all constraints are guaranteed). However, if your threads do multiple things in the same transaction, or even try to do their own transactions, the result might be incorrect for your program (as you have seen).

Comment: Can you please let me know what this SQLITE_CONFIG_SERIALIZED can do? What I thought is that if this option is enabled, we cannot update the database at the same time. And during the begin transaction, sqlite will be having a file handle lock to the database file right?, then how parallel deletion is possible with this option?

Comment: The "serialized" mode means that multiple threads can call functions on the same connection or statement, and that SQLite implements mutexes to serialize those calls. The effect is the same as if these calls were made one after the other in a single thread. However, you still cannot control the order of these calls. Therefore, using multiple connections is the only sane option.